# Is a quarry a kosher mikva?

Tags: halacha, mikvah-ritual-bath

I live near a [rock quarry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarry) that was discontinued and somehow filled with water.

I don't know exactly how this one was filled but from looking online it seems that usually what happens is that while the quarry is in use they constantly need to pump out ground water that seeps in and rain water that falls in... when they stop using the quarry and take out the pumps it eventually fills with this water.

Can it be used as a mikva?

Comment: For women*, I assume? *(Or men who want to actually be Tahor. - Double AA)

Comment: DesertStar If you could link to your online sources that would be helpful.

Comment: DesertStar, how is this different from a well?

Comment: http://www.scubaboard.com/forums/basic-scuba-discussions/72114-how-quarries-filled.html

Comment: http://www.dtmag.com/Stories/Dive%20Environments/08-06-feature.htm

Comment: My question is for men, women and dishes

Comment: Is "ground water" the same as a "spring"?  It indeed does seem to be similar to a well.

Comment: How sanitary is this?

Comment: @SethJ, it has fish and swimming is allowed by the county

Comment: More than you wanted to know about "ground water"... http://www.issaquah.org/comorg/gwac/hydro.htm

Comment: it would be prohibited to use b/c of the danger involved with using it b/c you could be putting your life in danger. rock quarries are known for having flash floods with very strong currents. Additionally there could be debris in the water which could seriously harm you as well while getting in and out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Aruch HaShulchan (YD 201:18, quoted below) rules that a man-made well dug in the ground is a kosher mikva by virtue of its status as a spring. He notes that springs are kosher mikvas whether or not the water flows or not, and notes that in most wells the water does flow in and out of the ground, but this is not a problem. Based on my online reading I see no geological difference between a well and your case of a quarry. Thus it seems the quarry is now a kosher mikva of the highest quality.

> מה נקרא מעיין הנהרות המושכים וכן הבארות החפורים ונמצא באר מים חיים דהמים הם ממעיינות והחפירה לא מקרי מעשה ידי אדם שהרי אין ידי אדם עושים בהמים כלל רק בהכיסוי שעל פני המים וזהו דומה למעיין גמור השוה לארץ והיה מכוסה ובא אדם ונטל הכיסוי ואין לשאול הא נתבאר דמעיין דרכו בזחילה ואנו רואים המים שבבארות נחים במקום אחד דאין זה שאלה כלל חדא דכבר נתבאר דמעיין מטהר גם באשבורן ועוד דבאמת גם בהבארות יש זחילה אלא שאינו ניכר לעין וראיה ברורה שהרי שואבין כל המים ולאחר שעה באים אחרים תחתיהם ומאין באו אם לא ע"י זחילה מגידי הארץ וגם הימים דינן כמעיין לטהר בזוחלין אף שאינם מים חיים לטבילת זב וצפורי מצורע וקידוש מי חטאת כדתנן במקואות